# Do alarms persist when quitting Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

If a Firefox add-on extension sets an alarm using [`browser.alarms.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/alarms/create) and then the user quits Firefox, will the alarm still exist the next time Firefox is opened?

If so, will alarms created using `delayInMinutes` be triggered immediately if the delay has been exceeded?

If so, will alarms created using `periodInMinutes` continue to be triggered based on the time of their initial firing before the browser was quit or the time of the browser being opened?

Answer (score 1):

Alarms do **not** persist across browser sessions.

The code below, when signed and installed (temporarily loaded extensions get unloaded when the browser quits), will output:

```
Extension running. Current alarms:
Array []
background.js:4:13
2019-03-16T17:15:10.841Z: Alarm should go off every minute. background.js:13:13
2019-03-16T17:16:10.912Z: test-alarm-1 background.js:16:17
2019-03-16T17:17:10.919Z: test-alarm-1 background.js:16:17
2019-03-16T17:18:10.922Z: test-alarm-1 background.js:16:17

​// Restart Firefox, reopen debugging.

Extension running. Current alarms: 
Array []
background.js:4:13
2019-03-16T17:18:40.689Z: Alarm should go off every minute. background.js:13:13
2019-03-16T17:19:40.796Z: test-alarm-1 background.js:16:17
```

If alarms persisted, the array would have 1 item.

manifest.json:

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test WebExtension",
    "author": "Jeremiah Lee",
    "developer": {
        "name": "Jeremiah Lee",
        "url": "https://www.jeremiahlee.com/"
    },
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "description": "Better documentation is needed",
    "homepage_url": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55173095/do-alarms-persist-when-quitting-firefox",
    "permissions": [
        "<all_urls>",
        "alarms",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "background": {
        "page": "./lib/background.html"
    }
}
```

background.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="module" src="./background.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

background.js:

```js
(async function() {
    const alarms = await browser.alarms.getAll();

    console.log(`Extension running. Current alarms:`, alarms);

    await browser.alarms.create(
        "test-alarm-1",
        {
            periodInMinutes: 1
        }
    );

    console.log(`${new Date().toISOString()}: Alarm should go off every minute.`);

    function handleAlarm(alarmInfo) {
        console.log(`${new Date().toISOString()}: ${alarmInfo.name}`);
    }

    browser.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(handleAlarm)
})();
```

Comment: I updated the documentation on MDN to reflect this behavior.